# Using fetch to download large files but using too much cache

Tags: javascript, download, blob, fetch-api

tl;dr: Is there any way to optimise this function to better handle the download of very large files?

I'm building this simple web app using JavaScript, where the user can download multiple type of files. Usually those files are .cpio archive, .mov or simply folders containing xyz other files.

The API (Synology) I'm working with to download the files is accurate about what it's returning in the header (application/zip, mov, zip etc. etc.) so every type of file is well handled, even folders are automatically compressed to zip.

My problem is that sometimes those files will weight more than 1GB and right now what happens is that everything is first loaded to RAM before being downloaded. For very large files ( > 2-3 GB ) this becomes a real system hog.

I need to find a way to bypass cache and right now, everything I have included in my request headers does nothing to help.

Here's my download function:

```
fetch(downloadURL, {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        cache: 'no-store',
        headers: {
            'pragma': 'no-cache',
            'cache-control': 'no-store'
        },
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.blob();
    })
    .then(blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Here's what's returned in the response headers by the API:

> Accept-Ranges: none
> Connexion: Keep-alive
> Content-Type: application/zip
> Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2019 09:00:00 GMT
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
> Server: ngix
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what solved my issue. At the end I think I focused too much on using fetch.
I realized that I could use the API query url to initiate the download using the download attribute compatible with Google Chrome.

```
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
```

Much more simple and no caching.